# Get the Attributes filter by using its display name?

Tags: ssas, mdx, analysis, cubes

I am trying to desgin a MDX query with Date filter which is an hierarchy attribute.. Now, I need to place the attribute filter value in the "where" clause.. When I drag and drop the attribute say - '2012', it gets converted to someother format like '[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Year].&[2.012E9]' whereas in leftpane display it shows as 'YR 2012'..

How do I control this conversion ? I am not sure on what basis it converts this attribute like that ?..

I need to build the MDX query dynamically in program based on the user selection.. How do I determine it is '2.012E9' when the user selectes '2012'? Or is there any way to alter the filter condition in MDX so that I can acheive this without using [2.012E9] string ?

Thanks in advance..

```
 SELECT 
[Subjects].[Name] on Rows,

[Student].Name  ON COLUMNS 
FROM Cube    
where 
 [Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Season].&[**2.0121E9**]

-- But the left side pane(Cube browser) shows the attribute as 'YEAR 2012'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each member has a `unique name` and a `display name`.
In the left pane you see the `display name`. In the Mdx query the key of the member is used (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237332%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)).

If you want to change the unique names you have to change your keys.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do this by changing the query like this:

SELECT 
[Subjects].[Name] on Rows,

[Student].Name  ON COLUMNS 
FROM Cube
where 
 **[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Season].[YEAR 2012]**